# Biblical Hebrew, לו and Gender Agreement (Psalm 3:2)

Tags: hebrew, grammar

> **Psalm 3:2 (WLC)** רבים אמרים **לנפשי** אין ישועתה **לו** באלהים סלה׃
>
> (My translation) They are many who say to **my soul,** 'There is no salvation **for him** with God.'"

### Question

"Soul" (נפש) is feminine, and "for him" (לו) is the masculine singular pronoun with the prefix ל. We would expect gender agreement if "it" was meant, however: is it possible for the masculine pronoun to be used in the "it" sense? That is, could this verse be translated, "They are many who say **of** my soul, '**It** has no salvation in God.'"

Answer (score 3):

The word נפשׁ can with a suffix also be used to form (reflexive) pronouns. See for example Isaiah 46:2, וְנַפְשָׁם בַּשְּׁבִי הָלָֽכָה "they (themselves; lit. *their soul*) went into captivity". You have translated the verse literally, but I would argue that leaving "soul" in the English suggests an emphasis on that concept which is absent in the Hebrew; I would rather translate "who say to me, ...".

This also explains why the 3ms suffix on ל does not agree *syntactically* with נפשׁ; it has *semantic* agreement with "me", the psalmist, instead. (Semantic agreement also occurs, for instance, when עם "people" occurs with a plural verb despite being singular morphologically—this phenomenon is widespread cross-linguistically.)

> is it possible for the masculine pronoun to be used in the "it" sense?

This assumes the Indo-European three-way gender distinction (masculine–feminine–neuter). The Semitic languages only have two genders (masculine–feminine), so I would be careful with this suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for that. I concur that retaining the literal "soul" could be misleading, as the emphasis produced in English is not present to the native Hebrew ear; but I think "soul" as idiomatic for 'person' is just that—I wouldn't go as far as to say 'it means' just the simple pronoun; that would be a step in the other direction as far as failing to reproduce the distinctions in the Hebrew, in my opinion, which aren't entirely redundant.

Comment: You're right that Hebrew has only masculine and feminine, however, I meant simply that can either (here masculine) be used in the equivalent sense to our English 'it.' E.g. Gn. 4:3: "Now it happened *that* [ויהי]" (literally, "and he happened").

Answer (score -1):

Interesting question. Could the problem be the incomplete translation of "ishuothe" in Psa. 3:3? The same term is fully translated in Isa. 62:1.

**Psa.3:2 [3:3]**

Many-ones (rbim 7227) ones-saying (amrim 559) to~soul-of~me (l~nphsh~i 5315) (there)-is-no (ain 369) **salvation [of her]** (**ishuoth~e** 3444) for~him (l~u 9999) in~Elohim (b~aleim 430) interlude (sle 5542):
 -

**Isa. 62:1**

As~(the)~brightness (k~nge 5051) righteousness-of~her (tzdq~e 6664) and~**salvation-of~her (u~ishuoth~e 3444)** as~torch (k~lphid 3940) he-shall-consume (ibor 1197):

Comment: According to the Masoretic vowelization, in which the word has penultimate stress and no *mappiq* in the letter ה, the word isn't possessive. In Isaiah the word is possessive

Comment: @b a Many elect not to use the Masorete system.